# How to include unused function in gcc

Tags: gcc

I am using g++ as my compiler for c++ code. I am creating a coverage report using lcov. I found that in coverage report unused functions are not even marked with count 0. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Are they inline/static functions? Maybe `-fkeep-inline-functions` (or static)?

Comment: @MarcGlisse they are class member functions defined inside class declaration, so yes they are inline. -fkeep-inline-functions have no effect over it.

Comment: It does for me. You will need to provide an actual example, as well as the compiler version and command line, so others can reproduce your issue.